# Wifi randomly drops on Windows 8 laptop

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, laptop, router

First of all, I did a lot of research on this problem, and I wasn't able to come to any helpful conclusion. I've finally decided that I need advice from those who might know *where* to look. So don't let me down. :P

I used to have an older Windows 7 laptop, which worked great for basic office and web browsing. However, I wanted something that would play actual modern games. So I recently bought a Sager NP8235 with the Intel Wireless-AC 7260 wifi card, and installed Windows 8 Pro on it. And ever since, I've been having problems with the wifi.

Generally, what happens is if I leave the laptop on but inactive for an extended amount of time (I've estimated it around an hour to two), the wifi will start dropping randomly. If I happened to have a download going at the time, it usually causes the download to fail. Or, if I put the laptop to sleep overnight, the next morning I usually have to restart the computer because the wifi device apparently stops working (it literally won't turn on). Also, and most frustrating, whenever I'm on a video chat (like Skype), after about ten minutes, the connection will start lagging like crazy, until it forces Skype to end the call. After that, I usually have to disable and reenable the wifi to get it working again.

I know it isn't our internet, because all the other computers in our house (~8) don't have any issues. Even the old Windows 7 laptop (connected also over wifi) works just fine, scoring the normal ~3Mbps average on speedtest.net (yes, I know our internet is slow, we live out in the country). Additionally, when I connect the Sager directly to the router via ethernet, the internet instantly starts working just great.

Like I said, I've done a lot of googling to figure out what's going on, and I haven't been able to find anything that worked for me. Is it Windows 8 conflicting with the Wifi drivers? As of this writing, I have the Intel drivers v16.1.5.2 installed (without the extra Intel software). Or is it our router? It's a TP-Link TL-WR841ND, set to the default settings. The Sager is currently being assigned to a static IP, if that makes any difference. And yet, the old windows 7 laptop has a much more stable connection than the Sager.

Anyone have any ideas? At this point, I'd appreciate even *knowing* what the problem is.

Comment: Its known that Intel WiFi adapters have lots of problems at least certain past models have problems like what you describe which are solved by using previous released drivers. Honestly I just disabled mine and got a USB wireless adapter because of all the problems I personally had. My problem was caused by heat personally.  You can try older released drivers but your problem is complicated by the fact the drivers must also supported Windows 8 and only the drivers with the problem seem to support Windows 8.

Comment: So we need to go over a few checkpoints to highlight the question: 1.How far is your laptop from the AP & does it get moved around a lot? 2. Are there any Wireless phones or a base station nearby? 3. Sometimes a microwave in the same room (like kitchen) could affect or interfere with the wireless connection. 4. Does anything in the environment change more or less the same time the Wifi disconnects? and then also, @Ramhound has got a really good point, I've seen laptops with freshly installed Windows 8 that has got some serious issues, due to using Windows 7 drivers (cause non support Win8)

Comment: @Rudolph - My point is that Intel's WiFi device drivers suck, have known problems, and only previous releases work ( good enough ) where they don't either lose 50% performance or experience problems where they simply stop working.  The problems would happe in Windows 7, the entire problem with Windows 8 literally is that, the updated drivers work with it but also have said problems.

Comment: @Rudolph 1. The laptop is in the room next to the room where the router is located, approximately 10ft away with only one wall in between. 2. I have a 2.4Ghz wireless mouse that I use with the laptop, but would it cause that much interference? I also used it with the Windows 7 laptop without a problem. 3. We don't have a microwave. 4. Not that I know of, aside from people walking by the room, possibly in between the router and the laptop. 5. This is a completely fresh install of Windows 8 Pro on a brand new Sager with no previous OS. I also have v16.1.5.2 Intel wireless drivers installed.

Comment: @Ramhound So the latest drivers are possibly the issue? Is there an older version of the drivers that has fewer problems but still works with Windows 8 (maybe not officially)?

Comment: @JosiahS - I stopped using my `Intel Wifi` Adapater years ago for because of problems like this.  It was a previous product clearly but still it had problems ( well documented ).